# Hadoop Map Task gets StackOverflowError

Tags: java, hadoop, stack-overflow

I'm seeing this exception in the syslogs of failed map tasks, all map tasks in a particular job are encountering this error.

Any guesses as to the cause here, this is a strange looking stack trace to my eyes.

```
2012-12-29 10:37:37,975 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child (main): Error running child : java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:80)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:64)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:117)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.DelegatingMapper.setup(DelegatingMapper.java:46)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.DelegatingMapper.run(DelegatingMapper.java:54)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.DelegatingMapper.run(DelegatingMapper.java:55)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.DelegatingMapper.run(DelegatingMapper.java:55)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.DelegatingMapper.run(DelegatingMapper.java:55)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.DelegatingMapper.run(DelegatingMapper.java:55)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.DelegatingMapper.run(DelegatingMapper.java:55)
    <1014 duplicate lines cut>
```

Comment: What do the logs look like on any of the individual nodes that fail?  (You should be able to get to them from the job tracker). Or are these from one of the nodes?

Comment: It's failing before it even runs any of your code, it seems to be related to your input files.  This is only a hunch, but do you have a lot of input files? What happens if you cut down the input to only a few files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking on sources of DelegationMapper.java I can suspect that you somehow set DelegationMapper to be your actual Mapper class. As a result - it infinitely delegates run to itself.

Comment: I'm working along these lines now. I notice one of my MultipleInput.add(...) statements was missing the final mapper class argument. That's a valid method signature though. I didn't follow the code all the way through to see what happens, but it was certainly a mistake so I'm working through a job with that fix in now and we'll see.

Comment: May be in this case it letf to be delegate mapper.

Comment: Seems like this was it. That one change caused it to work. I'll dig into it and try posting a bug report, that should not cause an infinite recursive loop.